# Redirecionar uma página com javascript ao abrir uma nova guia

Tags: javascript, redirecionamento-de-url

Preciso fazer o redirecionamento de uma página com javascript após submeter um formulário, o problema é que esse formulário abre em nova guia e após abrir essa nova guia eu preciso redirecionar a guia original para um novo endereço.

Usando o código abaixo eu não consigo fazer isso:

```
$("#gerarBoletoForm").on('submit', function(){
    window.location.replace('https://www.site.com.br/');
});
```

Nem mesmo se eu usar location.href ou location.assign.

Existe alguma forma de fazer isso?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Com base nas informações que vocês me passaram eu fui capaz de solucionar o problema.

Primeiramente setei o target do meu formulário numa nova janela criada por mim (e não o _target do form) após isso abri essa nova janela e atribui ela a uma variável e então submeto o formulário.

Após isso consigo usar o opener.location.href sem problemas. Abaixo deixo o código da solução:

```
$("#gerarBoletoForm").on('click', function(){
    document.gerarBoletoForm.target = "novaJanela";
    var boletoWindow = window.open("","novaJanela","toolbar=0");
    document.gerarBoletoForm.submit();

    boletoWindow.opener.location.href = "https://www.site.com.br/";
});
```

Dessa foi possível redirecionar a "janela mãe" sem problemas. Obrigado pela ajuda de todos!

PS: não sei se é a melhor solução mas foi possível resolver dessa forma.

Answer (score 1):

O objeto `window.opener` te dá acesso à aba "mãe". Com `window.opener.location.href` você vai poder controlar a url dela.

Comment: O problema é que não controlo a nova aba, ela é a aba do banco do brasil onde o boleto é gerado...

Comment: Quando o boleto é gerado a janela fecha? Se sim, é possível pegar esse evento.

Comment: Não fecha @lfarroco

Comment: O problema é que como o site alvo não tem a mesma origem (está no site do BB), você não pode acessar o conteúdo por segurança (cross-origin). Quando esse formulário do BB é enviado, algum servidor seu é notificado? Se sim, seria possível verificar pela janela original.